# Is it possible to replace android's browser default copy paste on text?

Tags: android

I am wondering if I could replace android's browser default copy paste on text. In which, user can long touch the text and then the toolbar will display the button of copy or paste. What I wanted to do is, whenever user long touch the text, my app will popup the menu under the selected text and they will be a button of copy and paste.

If the user click on copy, it will save into text file or sqlite for future reference. So that, all copied item won't lost.

Comment: I think it's very hard to do, or have no way to implement such behavior without modifying the code of android browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write  OnLongClickListener for your element in which your text resides that you want to be copied/pasted.

Example:

```
myTextView.setOnLongClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes totally possible.  On your edittext, just use

```
textview.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(callback)
where your callback will be a class the implements the
```

[ActionMode.Callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback.html)

On each of the callback methods that return a boolean simply return false.  This will prevent the default android behaivor of showing a copy/paste actions bar on long click.  Proceed to implement a textview.setOnLongClickListener(listener). In your listener, put your custom code to implement your custom menu.  This can be a context menu, or whatever you desire.